# Group results of joined table in sql

Tags: mysql

I have a users table and profile_visits table

I am trying to group visitors in profile_visits table

I tried

```
SELECT users.ID, COUNT(profile_visits.profile_id) AS b_count 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN profile_visits on profile_visits.profile_id = users.ID 
GROUP BY users.ID
HAVING COUNT(profile_visits.profile_id) > 1
ORDER BY users.ID ASC
```

With this, I can get total visitor numbers but I can't group the visitors

Any idea?

Comment: It's grouping the visitors by the profile they visited. How do you want it to be grouped?

Comment: Group by visitors which is profile_visits.user_id

Comment: "group the visitors" - group them how? The word "group" means different things to different people. Please post some example raw data and the result you expect to achieve for that raw data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count `profile_visits.user_id` rather than `profile_visits.profile_id`. And then use the `DISTINCT` modifier so you only count a visitor once, to get the number of unique visitors.

```
SELECT users.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT profile_visits.user_id) AS b_count 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN profile_visits on profile_visits.profile_id = users.ID 
GROUP BY users.ID
HAVING b_count > 1
ORDER BY users.ID ASC
```

Comment: I want to count multiple visits from same user as 1 visit. Basically I am trying to count visitors

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand you dont need user table at all

```
SELECT profile_id, COUNT(profile_visits.user_id) AS b_count 
FROM profile_visits
HAVING b_count > 1
ORDER BY profile_id ASC
```

Comment: check the answer if suitable